# Making crispy clothes easy to fold

Tags: clothing

Here in the UK, it is always wet so to dry clothes we put in on heating which dry it but makes the clothes crispy, which in turn makes them hard to fold. I want to know how to fold as it’s very hard to fold and laundry becomes a mess because we do laundry on weekend and it pile up really fast with no one want to fold up unless next weekend.

Comment: It may be helpful to give them an additional rinse with a small amount of Calgon.  There may be some soap residue that's causing the problem.

Comment: @aparente001 I thought calgon was for cleaning machine of residue.

Comment: It also prevents residue in the clothing. // Are you already using fabric softener in the final rinse? // It can help to set up an area where you can hang up clothes on hangers for a couple of days to air dry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wash them with something to help soften them; this can be a commercial fabric softener, or regular white vinegar. I've found this to prevent "crispness" when I've line-dried clothing.
2. "Break" the clothing when it's dry. Shake it hard with a "snapping" motion to loosen the fibers and make your clothing softer and easier to fold.

Answer (score 2):

1. Heat and dry them less. If you do that with a "machine", maybe the machine has some knobs or buttons, to adjust the results to the preferences.
2. After heating and drying, moist them mildly, with a fine spray or (better?) with steam, if you have. Let them rest until they lose the moist.
3. (Variant of 2.) You say that the air is wet anyway. After drying, let the clothes rest in the air, until they absorb some moist. When they become foldable, fold them.

(I hope I understood your problem correctly)

Comment: Put your clothes on clothes hangers straight out of the dryer. Then you won't need to iron them.